# 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Going crazy with this code.  Can Anybody put me on the right track?  I am using SQL Develope 3.1.07.  Thanks.

```
SELECT
    PHA.PO_HEADER_ID,
    PRLA.ATTRIBUTE1 As "REQUISITION_NUMBER",
    PHA.SEGMENT1 As PO_NUMBER,
    DECODE (nvl(REG.DOCUMENT_TYPE, '-'),
        'APW', 'Agreement for Performance of Work',
        'APWEMER', 'Agreement for Performance of Work - Emergency',
        'CONS', 'Consultant',
        'CONCEMER', 'Consultant - Emergency',
        'DFC', 'Direct Financial Contribution',
        'FELLOW', 'Fellowship',
        'GENEXT', 'General External Services',
        'IMPRESTCC', 'Imprest/Credit Card',
        'IS', 'Internal Services',
        'LOA', 'Letter of Agreement',
        'TSA', 'Technical Service Agreement') as DOCUMENT_TYPE,
   HAOU.NAME As BUDGET_CENTRE,
   PHA.CREATION_DATE As PO_CREATION_DATE,
   PHA.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS,
   PHA.APPROVED_DATE,
   PHA.COMMENTS,
   PHA.CLOSED_DATE,
   PHA.CLOSED_CODE,
   PDA.PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID,
   AIDA.INVOICE_ID,
   AIA.INVOICE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE AS INVOICE_TYPE,
   AIA.REMIT_TO_SUPPLIER_NAME AS SUPPLIER_NAME,
   AIA.REMIT_TO_SUPPLIER_ID AS SUPPLIER_ID,
   AIA.INVOICE_DATE, AIA.INVOICE_NUM,
   AIA.INVOICE_AMOUNT,
   AIA.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE AS INVOICE_CURRENCY,
   AIA.GL_DATE,
   AIA.PAYMENT_CURRENCY_CODE AS PAYMENT_CURRENCY,
   AIA.PAYMENT_CROSS_RATE_DATE AS PAYMENT_DATE,
   AIA.DESCRIPTION, AIA.EXCHANGE_DATE,
   AIA.EXCHANGE_RATE,
   AIA.BASE_AMOUNT AS FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY_AMOUNT
FROM
   po_headers_all pha,
   po_distributions_all pda,
   ap_invoice_distributions_all aida,
   ap_invoices_all aia,
   po_requisition_lines_all prla,
   po_req_distributions_all prda,
   hr.hr_all_organization_units haou,
   pa.pa_projects_all ppa
LEFT JOIN
   xxwrp.xxwrp_service_reg_all reg
ON
   reg.po_header_id = pha.po_header_id
WHERE
   1=1
   AND pha.segment1 = '201251390'
   AND pda.req_distribution_id = prda.distribution_id
   AND prda.requisition_line_id = prla.requisition_line_id
   AND pha.po_header_id = pda.po_header_id
   AND pda.po_distribution_id = aida.po_distribution_id
   AND aida.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
   AND pda.project_id = ppa.project_id
   AND haou.organization_id=ppa.carrying_out_organization_id
   AND pha.creation_date > aia.invoice_date
GROUP BY
   PHA.PO_HEADER_ID, PRLA.ATTRIBUTE1, PHA.SEGMENT1, REG.DOCUMENT_TYPE, HAOU.NAME, PHA.CREATION_DATE, PHA.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS, PHA.APPROVED_DATE, PHA.COMMENTS, PHA.CLOSED_DATE, PHA.CLOSED_CODE, PDA.PO_DISTRIBUTION_ID, AIDA.INVOICE_ID, AIA.INVOICE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE, AIA.REMIT_TO_SUPPLIER_NAME, AIA.REMIT_TO_SUPPLIER_ID, AIA.INVOICE_DATE, AIA.INVOICE_NUM, AIA.INVOICE_AMOUNT, AIA.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE, AIA.GL_DATE, AIA.PAYMENT_CURRENCY_CODE, AIA.PAYMENT_CROSS_RATE_DATE, AIA.DESCRIPTION, AIA.EXCHANGE_DATE, AIA.EXCHANGE_RATE, AIA.BASE_AMOUNT
```

When I run it, it returns this error:

> ORA-00904: "PHA"."PO_HEADER_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 50 Column: 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in mixing the old Oracle syntax with the ANSI join syntax; for example, say you have these tables:

```
create table t1(n1 number);
create table t2(n2 number);
create table t3(n3 number);
```

this is what you get:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from t1,t2
  3    left join t3 on t3.n3 = t1.n1
  4  where t1.n1 = t2.n2;
  left join t3 on t3.n3 = t1.n1
                          *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "T1"."N1": invalid identifier


SQL> select *
  2  from t1
  3    inner join t2 on t1.n1 = t2.n2
  4    left join t3 on t3.n3 = t1.n1;

no rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  What should I do then to fix the code?  Thank you.

Comment: The good way: completely switch to ANSI syntax. The short way: edit the `LEFT JOIN` part and use the `(+)` operator to make the outer join. I would strongly recommend the first choice.

Comment: Also, consider that some tools (Toad for Oracle for example) can switch a query from a syntax to another automatically

Comment: Thanks Aleksej.  Will check Toad this morning and will try to rewrite the code using ANSI.

Comment: ANSI code worked like a beauty.  Thanks for your help Aleksej.

Comment: If an answer is right for you, please consider accepting it; [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something more on what to do when someone answers you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your left join.  There is probably a column missing; the one you are joining on.

Here is more details on the error you're receiving:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00904.php